# Identify and extract or delete pages of a PDF based on a search string / text (action / javascript)

Tags: pdf, actionscript, acrobat

Good Evening (UK)

I'm trying to filter down a 1500+ page PDF file to only the pages which include a certain text string (typically one or two words). My laptop is locked down with respect to installing more software BUT I have used action(script)s quite a bit

I get the error below when I try to install this action into Abobe Acrobat X Pro (Win 7):
[screen dump of error](http://www.flickr.com/photos/johnbullas/12857671005/)

called "Extract Commented Pages"... supposed to be OK for X and XI this looks like what I want.....

I wondered if there was something simple causing the problem but the actionscript file is rather... busy to say the least.

I used to have an action that I think was based on a legal redaction script but it is filed somewhere!

If you have already got an action that does this or a version of the above that doesn't give the error I get (unable to import the Action.... The file is either invalid or corrupt) I will forever by indebted to your gratitude

Many thanks, have a good weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a script found at the following link: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1077118

I'm having some issues getting the script to run in Acrobat, despite everything looking alright in the script itself.  I'll update if I find any errors.

Here is a copy of the script:

```
// Set the word to search for here
var sWord = "forms";

// Source document = current document
var sd = this;
var nWords, currWord, fp, fpa = [], nd;
var fn = sd.documentFileName.replace(/\.pdf$/i, "");

// Loop through the pages
for (var i = 0; i < sd.numPages; i += 1) {

    // Get the number of words on the page
    nWords = sd.getPageNumWords(i);

    // Loop through the words on the page
    for (var j = 0; j < nWords; j += 1) {

        // Get the current word
        currWord = sd.getPageNthWord(i, j);

        if (currWord === sWord) {

            // Extract the current page to a new file
            fp = fn + "_" + i + ".pdf";
            fpa.push(fp);
            sd.extractPages({nStart: i, nEnd: i, cPath: fp});

            // Stop searching this page
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Combine the individual pages into one PDF
if (fpa.length) {

    // Open the document that's the first extracted page
    nd = app.openDoc({cPath: fpa[0], oDoc: sd});

    // Append any other pages that were extracted
    if (fpa.length > 1) {

        for (var i = 1; i < fpa.length; i += 1) {
            nd.insertPages({nPage: i - 1, cPath: fpa[i], nStart: 0, nEnd: 0});
        }
    }

    // Save to a new document and close this one
    nd.saveAs({cPath: fn + "_searched.pdf"});
    nd.closeDoc({bNoSave: true});

}
```